# Kernel compilation failed when enabled DEBUG

Tags: kernel, raspi-config, debug, makefile

I am compiling a kernel for my raspberry pi **(on the pi)**. I checked necessary configuration and enabled `DEBUG_INFO=y` and `REDUCED_DEBUG=n`.

But when I issue the command `make` I get the following error:

```
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: 'include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  LD      kernel/debug/kdb/built-in.o
kernel/debug/kdb/kdb_main.o: file not recognized: File truncated
scripts/Makefile.build:387: recipe for target 'kernel/debug/kdb/built-in.o' failed
make[3]: *** [kernel/debug/kdb/built-in.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'kernel/debug/kdb' failed
make[2]: *** [kernel/debug/kdb] Error 2
scripts/Makefile.build:455: recipe for target 'kernel/debug' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/debug] Error 2
Makefile:797: recipe for target 'kernel' failed
make: *** [kernel] Error 2
```

I could build my kernel and reboot it properly without the DEBUG_INFO etc. ( actually I had forgot to enable them) and I could load a module also.

How can I enable debugging feature and make this build. I Intend to write gpio drivers later.

Edit: Comment:

The Makefile has following for DEBUG_INFO:

```
ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += -g
KBUILD_AFLAGS   += -gdwarf-2
endif
ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_REDUCED
KBUILD_CFLAGS += $(call cc-option, -femit-struct-debug-baseonly) \
$(call cc-option,-fno-var-tracking)
endif
```

But I don't get it...what is this -femit-struct-debug-baseonly, -fno-var-tracking

Comment: Do a "make clean", then add "V=1" (i.e "make V=1") to the make command and post the last part of the compile process. V=1 will make the compile more verbose, so you can see what the actual error is. As for the extra options you have to read more about gcc's options: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html